# "'openid profile offline_access' is not valid" error when calling acquireToken method with code

Tags: azure-ad-msal, microsoft-identity-platform

I am using Authorization Code Flow. I want to get consent for two different audience/resource in one login popup.
So, I know that it is needed for `acquireToken` for first audience and then `acquireTokenSilently` for second audience.

However I got below error when calling acquireToken method:

> AADSTS28002: Provided value for the input parameter scope 'openid
> profile offline_access' is not valid when requesting an access token.
> Please specify a valid scope.

I remember that I didn't get this error when I tried this scenario last week.

Also, I didn't add the `openid, profile, offline_access` scopes, it is added to url automatically by the library.

Then below url is generated.

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?scope=openid+profile+offline_access+https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2FUser.ReadWrite.All+https%3A%2F%2Fteamsconfigapi-int.trafficmanager.net%2Fuser_impersonation&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Flogin&state=bd237c04-76b6-4a76-beca-fe4650c1f64d&nonce=3eab6371-df43-5cga-aded-a106fed74ab6&prompt=consent&client_id=56b7k4bh-8ce4-4b45-adkd-c51cdf5t52c2&response_mode=query
```

Note: Also, when I getting `https://graph.microsoft.com/User.ReadWrite.All` and `https://teamsconfigapi-int.trafficmanager.net/user_impersonation` consents separately(in two different login popup), there is no any problem. I can get `AuthenticationResult` objects both of them.

Why I got this error?

Answer (score 0):

You want to collect consent from two separate audiences/resources in one login popup, however you cannot get an access token for scopes that span more than one resource. You will need to request two access tokens for two different resources. The first can be accomplished using loginPopup, and the second can be accomplished using acquireTokenPopup or acquireTokenSilent.

Read more here: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-browser/docs/resources-and-scopes.md